# Missing Script "Start"

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I've deployed my bot's files but in the logs it says

```
2020-07-08T18:00:47.754261+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2020-07-08T18:00:47.762967+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-07-08T18:00:47.763212+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-07-08T18:00:47.763312+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-07-08T18_00_47_755Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you have a `start` script in your `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku uses the start script, if no Procfile exists.

**Useful links:**

[Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

[Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script)

[npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values)